# MQL5 reversing the array gives error

Tags: arrays, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to copy the `stochastic` function buffers in the variables. But what I see is that the candles are copied in the array in descending order.

```
double KArray[],DArray[];
ArraySetAsSeries(KArray,true);
ArraySetAsSeries(DArray,true);
int stochastic_output = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
CopyBuffer(stochastic_output,0,0,15,KArray);


CopyBuffer(stochastic_output,1,0,15,DArray);
for (int i=0;i < Candles_backtest_Stochastic_quantity;i++)
{
PrintFormat("K %d:  %f",i,KArray[i]);
PrintFormat("D %d:  %f",i,DArray[i]);

}
```

This works well and while printing the array values I am getting the `0th` as the current value and the previous values later.

```
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 0:  57.291667
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   D 0:  63.194444
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 1:  61.458333
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   D 1:  68.754756
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 2:  70.833333
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   D 2:  69.294286
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 3:  73.972603
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   D 3:  57.177428
2018.03.22 18:07:23.622 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 4:  63.076923
```

And so on.

But I want to have a reversed array, i.e. the `14th` array element must be the `0th` and the `0th` must be the `14th` element of the array.

I tried to make the `CopyBuffer()` statement to reverse the buffer, but got error, see the example:

```
2018.03.22 18:11:11.957   Total_back_lagANDvantage_required=3
2018.03.22 18:11:12.073 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K 0:  78.260870
2018.03.22 18:11:12.073 2018.02.01 00:00:00   D 0:  72.579331
2018.03.22 18:11:12.073 2018.02.01 00:00:00   array out of range in 'adxSTUDY.mq5' (173,33)
2018.03.22 18:11:12.073 OnTick critical error
2018.03.22 18:11:12.087 EURUSD,M1: 1 ticks, 1 bars generated. Environment synchronized in 0:00:00.312. Test passed in 0:00:00.594 (including ticks preprocessing 0:00:00.016).
2018.03.22 18:11:12.087 EURUSD,M1: total time from login to stop testing 0:00:00.906 (including 0:00:00.312 for history data synchronization)
```

Kindly, help me. I do not want to have another buffer to copy the array and reverse it, Is there a way through which I can reverse the array and use it?

Comment: try `ArraySetAsSeries(KArray,false)` before copying the buffer, alternative way is to know that `i`-th element in MQL4 mode is `array.length-1-i` and loop `(for int i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not want to have another buffer to copy the array and reverse it.

Right, each ***`copy`*** is expensive in two dimensions - in `[TIME]`-domain  and in `[SPACE]`-domain. There is for sure better way to avoid any copy to ever take place, for both of these reasons.

---

### There are two principal approaches:

**A )**
**the internal, native** MetaTrader Terminal / MQL5 modus operandi, which uses a sort of ***flag*** to indicate a reversed-time-stepping addressing on TimeSeries data, where **`[0]`** is being always the "***NOW***" - so changing the *flag* changes from native-addressing to "natural"-addressing, where `[0]` is a statically oldest ever cell, but the "NOW"'s address keeps creeping as time is moving forwards. This is the fastest method, yet requires designer to keep attention in which mode the access is set ( uses an On-Off-FSA ).

**B )**
a proxy-mode, where one can use an access function, which internally translates the access mode without having to pay attention to FSA-state.

Using class-based proxy became even easier way to go in proxy-based operation, as more class-methods allow for designing iterators and other tools, re-using the concept of autonomous proxy-abstracted details and prevent user from "damaging" the state of proxy-abstracted operations and fall outside of proper addressing in either of the actual `array[]`'s native-states.

B)-is not any slower than A), yet very handy to use, as one can stop remembering in what native-state the `array[]` has been left by the last operation, so a comfortable ( similarly if `array[]`-s get used for emulations of stack-based ops and other higher-level of abstraction data-structures in MQL4/5 domains ).

Answer (score 2):

Use the ArraySetAsSeries function. In your case it will be

```
ArraySetAsSeries(KArray,false);
```